# How to inject configuration in a custom Spring Data JPA repository

Tags: java, spring, repository, spring-data-jpa

I want to add a custom bulk save method based on the code from [JPA batch inserts with Hibernate & Spring Data](https://frightanic.com/software-development/jpa-batch-inserts/) to all Spring Data JPA repositories in my application. The [Spring Data doc explains how this can be done](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories) with a custom repository base class like the one shown below. My question is how to set the `batchSize` property in the example below. Injection with @Value as shown below does not work.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BulkRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
  extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

  void bulkSave(Iterable<T> entities);
}

public class BulkRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements BulkRepository<T, ID> {

  private final EntityManager entityManager;

  @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}")
  private int batchSize;

  public BulkRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation entityInformation,
                          EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(entityInformation, entityManager);   
     this.entityManager = entityManager;
  }

  public void bulkSave(Iterable<T> entities) {
    // implementation using batchSize goes here
  }
}
```

Do I have to use a custom `JpaRepositoryFactoryBean` to build a configured `BulkRepositoryImpl`? Or is there a more direct way?

Comment: how do you set the "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value?

Comment: "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" is set in the application.properties. My question is how to get the value from there into the BulkRepositoryImpl instances.

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: The BulkRepositoryImpl is created without an error. The problem is just that batchSize is not set (has the default value 0).

Comment: Did you try to inject the value via constructor?

Comment: I did but it does not work. The JpaRepositoryFactory requires a constructor taking exactly the parameters shown in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across the exact same problem and could not find any way around defining my own `JpaRepositoryFactoryBean` class. It seems that the dependencies of the custom repository base class are not automatically injected the way they are in a standard bean (see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/14a56dee00c1651573c41b601b653c88af3a3c69/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/RepositoryFactorySupport.java#L191) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/14a56dee00c1651573c41b601b653c88af3a3c69/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/RepositoryFactorySupport.java#L346)). Also, when creating instances of repository interfaces, the default `JpaRepositoryFactory` only passes instances of `JpaEntityInformation` and `EntityManager` to the class constructor (see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/bcf9cfdf50a5154cd877780fd14c00b59d70dc47/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/JpaRepositoryFactory.java#L102)). This, as far as I can tell, effectively prevents you from including additional dependencies for classes extending `SimpleJpaRepository`.

I ended up defining the custom factory the following way:

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc")
public class RepositoryConfiguration {
    private int batchSize;
}

public class MyCustomRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

    private RepositoryConfiguration repositoryConfiguration;

    public MyCustomRepositoryFactoryBean(Class<? extends R> repositoryInterface, RepositoryConfiguration repositoryConfiguration) {
        super(repositoryInterface);
        this.repositoryConfiguration = repositoryConfiguration;
    }

    @Override
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        return new MyCustomRepositoryFactory(entityManager, repositoryConfiguration);
    }

    private static class MyCustomRepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

        private RepositoryConfiguration repositoryConfiguration;

        MyCustomRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager, RepositoryConfiguration repositoryConfiguration) {
            super(entityManager);
            this.repositoryConfiguration = repositoryConfiguration;
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        protected SimpleJpaRepository<?, ?> getTargetRepository(RepositoryInformation information, 
                EntityManager entityManager) {

            JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation = 
                    (JpaEntityInformation<T, ?>) getEntityInformation(information.getDomainType());

            return new MyCustomRepositoryImpl<T, I>(
                    entityInformation, 
                    entityManager, 
                    repositoryConfiguration);
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            return MyCustomRepositoryImpl.class;
        }
    }
}
```

While it is not possible to inject fields with `@Value` in `MyCustomRepositoryFactoryBean` either, Spring resolves the dependencies passed to the constructor, so you can just provide your properties through a bean (`RepositoryConfiguration` in the code above) and pass it down to `MyCustomRepositoryImpl`. Lastly, you will need to instruct Spring Data to use your `FactoryBean` class when creating repositories by adding

```java
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        repositoryFactoryBeanClass = MyCustomRepositoryFactoryBean.class
)
```

to a `@Configuration` annotated bean. It's a lot of boilerplate, but it works.

N.B. I am using `spring-data-jpa:1.11.8.RELEASE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from EntityManager.

```
String defaultBatchSize = "100";
String batchSizeString = (String) entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getProperties()
                         .getOrDefault("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", defaultBatchSize);
batchSize = Integer.parseInt(batchSizeString);
```